# In a lead screw mechanism with a fixed travelling nut, will the screw and its driving mechanism move instead?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motion

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/tUkkOStjz8o

Imagine this but upside down.

Since the platform bolted to the travelling nuts will be pressed against the ground and will have nowhere to go, I reckon the the platform with the motor & gearboxes on it will move up and down. Am I correct?

Comment: Please post a screengrab of the device in your question so that we don't have to watch a video to understand it. It also ensures that your question makes sense if the YouTube link dies.

Comment: Apologies. Thank you fr the tip and for fixing my mistake :)

Comment: the two parts move relative to each other ... it makes no difference if one of the parts is attached to ground, or if both are hanging in the air

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The ballscrews control the relative position of the base and the platform. Fixing one in space will cause the other to move.

Comment: So if this entire assembly is turned upside down, the surface with motor and gearboxes will move up and down, right?

Comment: If the platform with the ball-nuts is fixed in space then the motor-gearbox platform must move.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Transistor the last sentence is unclear .... the two parts move relative to each other even if they are not attached to anything

Comment: @jsotola, you are correct. I used too many words.